# Why can I not recover my Monero wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, wallet-recovery, ledger, keys-file, password-confirmation

The Monero GUI wallet does not accept my password and I do not have the mnemonic seed or written down keys. I have attempted to recover it using the `.keys` file, but after choosing `"Open wallet from file"`, it still asks for the password, that it does not accept. I have downloaded the official wallet from [getmonero.org](https://getmonero.org) and I'm using a Ledger Nano.

How can I recover the wallet?

Comment: You can simply regenerate / recreate the Ledger Monero wallet files, see -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/how-do-i-restore-recreate-my-ledger-monero-wallet | Also, for the current wallet, have you tried using a blank password? That is, just leaving the password field blank and hitting enter.

Comment: tried without the password and get a message "not connected to network" and "start daemon". Not sure how to do that. Also, it seems that the instructions on how to recreate Monero Ledger wallet files assume that I have the mnemonic words, which I do not have.  I only have .keys file, but not the keys themselves.

Comment: First of all, the 24 word seed provided by the Ledger device upon initializing it *is* your Monero seed. However, do not, under any circumstances, enter it into the GUI.  Regarding your "not connected to the network" issue,  could you perhaps temporarily try using a remote node? https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/remote_node_gui.html

Answer (score 1):

You can restore a wallet by either using the keys, .keys file, the password or the 25-word mnemonic seed.

You can learn more about reading these answers:
[How can I recover a wallet using the mnemonic seed?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10/how-can-i-recover-a-wallet-using-the-mnemonic-seed) or [Restoring Wallet from Keys file](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/restoring-wallet-from-keys-file/10721#10721).